# Unable to override externalUserBuilder in Federated Authentication implementation

Tags: federated-authentication, owin

I have implemented facebook login on my Sitecore site using federated authentication. I am trying to override the externalUserBuilder logic to be able to replace the hashed username in Sitecore with the email id as indicated here: http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2018/03/sitecore-federated-authentication-part-3-sitecore-user-and-claims-identity.html

However, it looks like the code isn't getting executed at all. Any breakpoint in this code isn't being hit, and the user name created is still the hash.

[image]

```
namespace Feature.Accounts.Pipelines.IdentityProviders
{
    public class CustomExternalUserBuilder : DefaultExternalUserBuilder
    {
        public CustomExternalUserBuilder(string isPersistentUser) : base(bool.Parse(isPersistentUser)) { }

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1726:UsePreferredTerms", MessageId = "Login")]
        protected override string CreateUniqueUserName(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ExternalLoginInfo externalLoginInfo)
        {
            //TODO: If Email
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)userManager, nameof(userManager));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)externalLoginInfo, nameof(externalLoginInfo));
            IdentityProvider identityProvider = this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration.GetIdentityProvider(externalLoginInfo.ExternalIdentity);
            if (identityProvider == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to retrieve identity provider for given identity");
            string domain = identityProvider.Domain;
            return domain + "\\" + externalLoginInfo.Email;

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me with what I am missing here?

Comment: 1. Can you show all your "mapEntry" nodes?
2. Make sure that you don't try to debug your CustomExternalUserBuilder class when the user under the test already exists in the DB.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Closing this since it's unresolved/abandoned by OP

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to do this is as follows:

```
<externalUserBuilder type="MyProject.Utility.OktaUserBuilder, MyProject" patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']">
    <param desc="isPersistentUser">false</param>
</externalUserBuilder>
```

Comment: The reason this works is, the user builder is called on every login for virtual users. For persistent ones, the right place to hook in is the property mapper.